# Formal definition of an algorithm that outputs the cardinality of a hereditarily finite set

Tags: algorithms, set-theory, formal-languages

Let our alphabet consist of three elements: the left brace {, the right brace }, and the comma $,$. Suppose we have already defined the language $L$ over that alphabet which represents the [hereditarily finite sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hereditarily_finite_set). So, for instance, the string $\{\}$ would represent the empty set, and the string $\{\{\},\{\}\}$ would represent the singleton of the empty set. I want to define, formally, an algorithm or computer program that takes a string $s$ from $L$, and outputs a nonnegative integer which is the cardinality of the hereditarily finite set which is represented by $s$. So, for instance, the algorithm would output $0$ to the string $\{\}$, $1$ to the string $\{\{\}\}$, and also $1$ to the string $\{\{\},\{\}\}$. Can someone give me the definition of such an algorithm?

Comment: What do you allow yourself? Do you allow recursive algorithms?

Comment: This seems more of a programming question than a math question. Also, have you tried writing a program to do the task yourself? (It may help to first consider the case where the input string is guaranteed to be "duplication-free," since then this reduces to simple curlybrace matching.)

Comment: I'm going to assume you already know how to turn a string from L into a hereditarily finite *list*, since that's more of a programming problem.  The next step is to determine whether two lists represent the same set.  This can be done recursively using the axiom of extensionality: they represent the same set if and only if for every element x of the first list, there is an element y of the second list that represents the same set as it, and vice versa.  Then it remains to go through the top-level list and count only the elements that do not represent the same set as any of their predecessors.